# How to breakdown table into query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am new to database and programming world, so I have table for example :

```
code_8dg | year | total_value
-----------------------------
01061900 | 2017 |  1521
01061900 | 2017 |  55396
01061900 | 2018 |  38281
01061900 | 2018 |  21224
```

I want to breakdown this `code_8dg` into `2dg, 4dg, 6dg, 8dg` like

```
2dg |  4dg  |  6dg   |   8dg    | year | total_value
---------------------------------------------------
 01 | 0106  | 010619 | 01061900 | 2017 |  1521
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Also [ask] (especially about homework), hits googling 'stackexhange homework' & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Please show some work with justification, explain about the first place you get stuck & ask a specific question about it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `left()`:

```
select left(code_8dg, 2) as code_2dg,
       left(code_8dg, 4) as code_4dg,
       left(code_8dg, 6) as code_6dg,
       code_8dg as code_8dg,
       year, total_value as value
from t;
```

I'm not sure why you only want one row.  But you can use a `where` clause for filtering.